# Why is the function argument undefined?

Tags: matlab, octave

Apparently this might be a banal error, but I cannot figure out how to do it correctly (my first day with octave). I want to define the second order ODE **d²x/dt² + M/L * dx/dt + 5x = 0** as system of ODEs. `ODE2.m` looks like this:

```
function dz = ODE2(z,t)
  %% d^2x/dt^2 + M/L * dx/dt + 5x = 0
  M = 2;
  L = 10;
  dz = zeros(2,1);
  dz(1) = z(2);       % <--- apparently here's something wrong?!
  dz(2) = -(M/L)*z(2)-5*z(1);
end
```

Then I do

```
t = linspace(0,1,100);
z = lsode(ODE2,[1;1],t);
...
```

But I get

```
error: 'z' undefined near line 6 column 11
```

However, I thought `z` is defined as argument in the first line of `ODE2.m`. Maybe the problem is that `z` is a vector and this is unknown at definition time, but how to do it properly than? How to define the equation and solve it with `lsode`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the call `z=lsode(ODE2,[1;1],t);`, `ODE2` is interpreted as a function call, which will evaluate the function and then run into the issue that there are no input arguments. Note you will get the same error if you split the statement into `fun=ODE2; z=lsode(fun,[1;1],t);`

Assuming that Octave works the save way as Matlab, you need to pass the reference to `ODE2` as a function handle, `z=lsode(@ODE2,[1;1],t);` will work.

Comment: I noticed, that if I use `lsode` to solve an ode defined via an  anonymous function (e. g. `ode = @(x,t) x;`), in this case I need to write `x = lsode (ode,0.1,t);` (at least in octave). Why is that?

Comment: Hint: what happens if you type `ode` (handle to your defined anonymous function) at the command line? What about if you type in the name of a function? What is returned in each case?